# Looking for a low footprint solution to GROUP rows using HAVING to filter

Tags: mysql

Here is a table

```
id    date     name
1     180101      josh
2     180101      peter
3     180101      julia
4     180102      robert
5     180103      patrick
6     180104      josh
7     180104      adam
```

I need to get all the names whom having the same days as 'josh'. how can i achieve it without groupping the whole table together. i need to keep it efficient (this is not my real table, i just simplified my problem here, and i have hundred thousands of records, and 99% of the rows have different dates, so groupable rows by date is kind of rare).

So basicaly what i want is: if 'josh' is the target, i need to get 'josh,peter,julia,adam' (actually the first 10 distinct names sharing the same date with josh).

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(date) as datecount,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) as names,  
FROM  
    table 
GROUP BY  
    date
HAVING 
     datecount>1
     // && name IN ('josh') would work nice for me, but im getting error because 'name' is not in GROUPED BY
LIMIT 10
```

Any idea ? As i mentioned it needs to be fast, and most of the rows have unique dates

Comment: 180101 IS NOT  a date what datatype is it?

Comment: this table is just a madeup one, that is not important, i could write colorcodes instead of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table with itself on `date`:

```
select distinct t1.name
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 using (date)
where t2.name = 'josh'
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6hyfNMeKxhbALZMq5jDK6p/0)

For the best performance you would have indexes on `(name)` and `(date, name)`.

Comment: Thank you Paul ! Never used 'using' keyword before, but it is working nicely

Comment: `USING(date)` is equivalent to `ON t1.date = t2.date`. Very handy if you join on multiple columns of same name.

Comment: Oh ok. that is a lot more familiar